# How to declare a vector of n strings in a class in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class abc
{
   public:
          std::vector<std::string> other_license_files(30);
};
```

This should declare a vector of 30 elements, each an empty string. But i get the error
expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant.

C++ primer doesn't say about using this within a class though in pg 98. Suppose this would be alright from a function. I don't know where else this information could be.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> other_license_files = std::vector<std::string>(30);`. OR, in the constructor, in member init list: `: other_license_files(30)`.

Comment: If there are always a fixed 30 strings you may want `std::array<std::string,30> other_license_files;` instead

Comment: or `std::string myLovelyVec[30];` ... for C lovers ...

Answer (score 1):

What you've run into is the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)!

The short answer is that the compiler thinks you're declaring a member function which returns a `std::vector<std::string>` rather than a member variable.

The typical solution is to use a constructor and pass the argument there. However,  since you're using C++11 you can use curly braces. [Here's an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YY5nWr):

```cpp
#include <vector> // std::vector
#include <string> // std::string

class foo {
public:
    // error: expected identifier before numeric constant
    // std::vector<std::string> bad_member_(30);

    // OK!
    std::vector<std::string> member_{30};
};


auto bar() {
    foo f;
    return f.member_.size();
}
```